# Grails Events: Copying directories around at Build time to get a clean 'multi-tenant' deployment effect

Tags: grails, ant

I'm working on a sort of 'multi-tenant' grails app that will be used as a 'platform' upon which quick sites will be developed.

A 'site' will include a layout, images, and page gsps.

Right now, these are spread across the project in their normal locations, eg:

```
/grails-app/views/layout
/grails-app/views/<site>
/web-app/images/
```

Ideally, they'd all be in one place, centralized by site, like

```
/sites/<site>/layout
/sites/<site>/pages/
/sites/<site>/imagtes
```

My current thinking is this could be accomplished with a Build.groovy script and doing some ant trickery at build time.
But I'm not sure if it's possible to do this copying-by-convention - ie I don't know the directories that are present until it runs. (I'm also no ant guru)

Any ideas/suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following script, named _Events.groovy and located in a scripts folder under your grails application, to copy files before my build:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsEvents")

 eventSetClasspath  = { msg ->
    println "Custom Configuration"
    ant.copy(todir:classesDirPath) {
        fileset(dir:"${basedir}/config")
    }
 }
```

And I suppose you could use something very similar.

Relevant grails documentation is [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/4.%20The%20Command%20Line.html#4.3%20Hooking%20into%20Events)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion- I think this is the right direction, but my stumbling point is how to know what directories are there.. ie I'd need to 1- find what dirs are under sites/, then 2- foreach dir found, 3- copy the subdirs under it to the 'real' locations.  With your comment I should be able to do 2 and 3, but still unsure about 1.

Comment: the event has access to all the project metadata and is written entirely in groovy. just use listFiles() for that folder, and pick up the subfolder u need depending on environment variables or project metadata.

Comment: ah ok then - so something like new File("${basedir}/sites").list() .. that should work just fine.  Thanks for the advice, it seems like everything I might need is available (grails metadata + java file classes), so I should be able to do what I need.